# Python sentiment / text analysis advice

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, sentiment-analysis

I don't know if this is the right place to ask this but, i am trying to build a bot in Python that will read incoming messages on a Slack channel where customer post their issues such as 'unable to connect to VPN', 'can someone reply to my ticket' etc…

The bot will analyze the message, determine if the customer is angry or not, and then propose a solution until an agent is free to actually check the issue.

Now, I was experimenting with TextBlob for the sentiment analysis part, but I don't know which technologies to actually use to determine the issue based on specific keywords and provide a solution to the user. Can someone propose me some python libraries/technologies that I could use to achieve this ?

Comment: I think this will get closed as asking for opinion and/or lacks focus. I'd try googling for spacy tutorials, as spaCy tend to be quite practical. Not sure what you had in mind for "specific keywords" but one comes up on "aspect-based sentiment analysis" that looks interesting.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this issue?

Answer (score 0):

To be honest your question is to generic to answer in one go.

Nontheless, you first have to clearly define the scope of your project. In doing so, you might want to first do a quick literaty review (Google Scholar) to familiarize with the state of the art technologies and methods.

From my little experience, a common (maybe simple) technique (lexicon-based approach) used to determine the sentiment of a word, is to use a pre-compiled dictionary (you can create your own though) that contains words - sentiment mappings. For example:

`word:tired, sentiment:negative, score:5`

So each time the bot finds the keyword "tired" in a sentence it will assign its corresponding negative value (polarity) to the sentence.

You might want to consider applying `POS tags` in the input text, as sometimes `nouns` or ``verbs carry significant meaning, compared to `adjectives` for example.

Keep in mind though, that negative comments can be written in the form of `sarcasm`. Sarcasm detectioin is a more difficult task though.

Alternatively, you could try using a pre-trained model such as `bert-base-multilingual-uncased-sentiment` that can be found [here](https://huggingface.co/nlptown/bert-base-multilingual-uncased-sentiment?text=I%20like%20you.%20I%20love%20you) in Hugging Face.

For more information on the matter you have a look at this [post](https://www.unite.ai/10-best-python-libraries-for-sentiment-analysis/).

Again as I mentioned, you have to clearly define your goals. This will enable you to specify the libraries or methodology available to solve your problem. Hope my answer helps.

Comment: we provide support for multiple applications such as slack, okta, cloudflare etc. We have a channel where users posts there issues. I want to create a link from the message to the application that we support so that my bot can redirect the appropriate documentation or support until an agent actually replies them. Thr link between the message and the keywords is what i need.